# is it possible to make chat app in node without using socket.io

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io, chat

I want to make small chat app in [**nodejs**.](http://nodejs.org/)

But every where i found that to achieve this functionality **node** is used with **[socket.io](http://socket.io)**

As **node** was also created with **push notification** in mind so thinking

How to create chat app purely in node if possible ?

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure what "purely in node" means.

Comment: "purely in node" means : As node was also created with push notification in mind so its like why use other library :>)

Comment: Definitely possible, but depends on your requirements. What stops from using socket.io? You want to end up with the same functionality that socket.io has, you will eventually write something that's does what socket.io except. But the question is why do you want spend time doing this when socket.io provides the functionality? node was created with push notification in mind, but socket.io functionality is not baked in it. You have to write it from scratch.

Comment: @FaridNouriNeshat many shared hosting servers don't support socket.io

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I want to make small chat app in nodejs. But every where i found that
>   to achieve this functionality node is used with socket.io.  As node
>   was also created with push notification in mind so thinking How to
>   create chat app purely in node if possible ?

Yes, it is possible to create a node.js application that supports chat without using socket.io.  You have these choices:

1. Use a straight webSocket to "push" to the client.  You will need to find or write your own server-side code for handling the webSocket protocol because such code is not built into node by default.  The [ws module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws) is one such library.  If using a plain webSocket, you will likely have to implement on your own some of the functionality that socket.io implements such as auto-reconnect.
2. Find some other library (besides socket.io) that is built on top of a webSocket that would let you push data to a client.
3. Invent your own substitute for a webSocket (probably client polling or long polling) and code that.  This is what was done before webSockets existed.  It is much less efficient than a continuously connected webSocket.

All of these choices involve writing some code that has already been written for you in socket.io so most developers would rather just use the already working and already tested solution rather than reimplement it themselves.

---

To get into further detail in your question, you will need to define what "purely in node" means to really answer this question.  That's not a well defined term.  The socket.io library is just a library written in Javascript just like thousands of other libraries you can use in node.js to get your job done.

As you quickly see with node programming, you can't do very much at all in a default node instance without loading other libaries.  Some of these libraries come with a default installation of node (like the `fs` library or `http` library, for example) and others are libraries that you install before using (usually as simple as typing `"npm install socket.io"`) and then `var io = require("socket.io");`.

If you are not going to use the socket.io library, then you need a mechanism for "pushing" data to a client in order to make a chat application work.  The only true "push" that has any cross-browser support is a webSocket.  A webSocket is what socket.io uses.  You could use a webSocket from node without using socket.io, but you'd have to write or find code that implements the webSocket protocol that you can run on node (the [ws module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws) is one such library).  Such code is not built into node by default.

If you weren't going to use webSocket, then there is no other cross-browser method to "push" data to a browser client.  Your only other alternative I'm aware of would be browser polling which isn't actual push, but tries to simulate push by just regularly asking the server if the server has anything new for a particular client.  An enhancement to straight polling is "long polling" which was invented before we had actual push with webSockets.

All of this problem has already been solved in socket.io so unless you really just want your own research project to rebuilt similar functionality in your own code, you may as well build on solutions that have already been done by using something like the socket.io library.

If you have some specific objection to the socket.io library, then please explain that objection so we can understand what your real goal is here.

Comment: WebRTC is another "cross-browser method to 'push' data to a browser client", although, it is not pushing from a Node server.

Answer (score 2):

Node.js doesn't come with an out-of-the-box server-side Websocket implementation, so you will have to, at least, introduce a package which does.

If you don't want to go with `socket.io`, you can then defer to [`ws`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws), which is what `socket.io` uses under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a chat application with Node.js and a database without using WebSocket. However, it's important to understand that using a database for real-time chat introduces additional complexity and potentially increases latency, as you won't have the direct, low-latency communication provided by WebSocket.

Here's a simplified approach to building a chat application with Node.js and a database:

Set Up a Node.js Server: Create a Node.js server using Express.js or another framework.

Handle HTTP Requests: Set up routes to handle HTTP requests for sending and receiving messages. When a client sends a message, save it to the database. When a client requests chat history, retrieve messages from the database and send them back to the client.

Use a Database: Choose a database system like MongoDB or PostgreSQL to store chat messages. Create a schema to represent messages, including fields like sender, receiver, timestamp, and content.

Implement Authentication: Implement user authentication to ensure that only authenticated users can send and receive messages. You can use libraries like Passport.js for authentication.

Frontend Client: Develop a frontend client using HTML, CSS, and JavaScript (possibly with a frontend framework like React or Vue.js). Use AJAX or Fetch API to send HTTP requests to the server for sending and receiving messages.

Real-Time Updates (Optional): If you want to provide real-time updates without WebSocket, you can use techniques like polling or long-polling. However, these techniques are less efficient and scalable compared to WebSocket.